# Performance advantage or disadvantage of using multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, wcf

I am just a beginner in WCF services and I have a general public use website that runs its business logic in a remote WCF service and accessed worldwide. I divided each feature of website into 10 service contracts on WCF service. These 10 service contracts are implemented by one service class. And there can be more service contracts.

What I want to know that is it a good idea or bad if we take performance under consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience implementing WCF services for several high performance systems, we have not seen a definitive performance advantage using either single or multiple service contracts.  As such, our team would base the separation of operations into service contracts based on general, "best practice" software design principles.  Regarding WCF Service performance, I recommend consideration of the following aspects:

- Binding
- Throttling
- Serializer
- Caching
- Client connectivity

The following links provide good reference:
http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/wcf-performance-tuning/

Regards,